# CSV to Excel conversion using Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I wrote a piece of code that parse a .csv and save the data in excel format.
The problem is that all my data in excel appear as "number stored as text" and i need the data starting with column 3 to be converted as number type so i can represent it using a chart.
My table is looking something like this:

```
    C1     C2       C3
R1  BlaBla          36552.00233102 ...
R2         App1     3484.000000000 ...
R3         App2     3399.000000000 ...
.....................................
```

and this is the code:

```
f = open("csv_file")
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for i in reader:
    ws.append(i)

f.close()
wb.save("excel_file")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your CSV file contain numeric elements that are in quotation marks? If so, that would result in what you're seeing. For example, consider this:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for i in [['100', 100]]:
    ws.append(i)    
wb.save("excel_file.xlsx")
```

The `str` value is written as a text element in Excel while the `int` value is written as a number. If your CSV file contains

```
"100", 100
```

`csv` would interpret that as a string and a number.

You could convert everything in column three onwards from your `csv` file by adding:

```
i[2:] = [float(x) for x in i[2:]]
```

to the line right before you append `i` to your workbook.

Comment: I added i[2:] = [float(x) for x in i[2:]] like you said and works perfectly.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. Fixed in my answer.

Comment: Worth noting that openpyxl has an option for workbooks to "guess" the type of value which probably work in this case. But I'd always recommend you handle the conversion yourself. `wb.guess_types=True` is the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't defined what column is a float, you can try to convert the value to float with an exception handler.
The code could become:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for i in reader:
    try:
        ws.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        ws.append(i)

f.close()
```

Answer (score -3):

I suggest to use pandas
pandas.read_csv and pandas.to_excel